# Duplicate interface definition for class 'RCTViewManager' XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

I added AirBnb's React Native Maps to my project following their installation instructions:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

And now I get these compile errors when trying to build the project with Xcode. The app still runs if I use "react-native run-ios" in terminal, but I want to resolve this issue. I tried the solutions proposed in this following link but it did not fix anything:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1017

Originally there were actually multiple of these errors for different React Native classes, but they were fixed when I replaced the relevant imports from quotation mark syntax to <> syntax.

For example, if the error is for 'RCTView', I would replace `#import "RCTView.h"` with `#import <React/RCTView.h>`

However, this did not fix this error, which is the only one left.

I've included relevant screenshots below:

[image: This is what the error looks like.]

[image: Pod File]

[image: Link Binary Libraries]

Huge thanks to anyone that can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue! I changed the podfile so that the commented out the used pod 'React'... line and uncommented the other one, and then followed the solution here:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/789

Comment: Can you please add your update solution to the answer? That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All the files in `ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core/React/` are supposed to be `Symbolic Links` to node modules React folder.

So the file at `ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core/React/RCTViewManager.h` should be a symbolic link to `../../../../../../node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTViewManager.h`.

Do this to all the files in that directory and you won't have a `Duplicate interface definition` error.

---

In my case, I didn't have the symbolic link but the whole file copied in the Pods. Which caused twice the declaration of interfaces.

I know it's a very old question, but I recently solved the same issue. Maybe it could help someone else too.

Comment: I am facing same issue in xcode 14 and RN 68. May I know what do you mean by symbolic link?

Comment: @ThinkAndCode Symbolic link is like a "shortcut" in Windows terminology. A file that actually refers to a different file.

I faced this issue because I had the same files in both folders. You should have the files only in `node_modules`, and `Pods` folder must only have the shortcut (symbolic links) to the actual files.